# Get a unique refernce id for a Django object

Tags: python, django

I want to create a function in my `Django` project to ensure the uniqueness of the reference ID for each user who joins my website, but when `join` is being clicked I get this error:

```
Join matching query does not exist.
```

This is my function:

```
def get_ref_id():
    ref_id = str(uuid.uuid4())[:10].replace('-','').lower()
    id_exists = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)
    if id_exists:
        get_ref_id()
    return ref_id
```

Comment: *tip:* use `uuid4().hex` instead of that weird string stuff that you're doing

Comment: i just did that but the reference Id not created at all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.get` on a django model will raise an exception if the query doesn't exist.  So this line is not making sense:

```
id_exicts = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)
```

Probably you wanted instead

```
id_exicts = Join.objects.filter(ref_id=ref_id).exists()
```

Or, you can catch the `Join.DoesNotExist` exception from the `.get` and build your logic that way.

Comment: i have a question if you don't mind to help .
the course that a follow to teach me use the same .get with try and except statements but it works . why ?